# Test recaptcha with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using recaptcha gem and I need to cover the alternative scenario on test spec (when captcha  is not valid)

This is the code that the gem suggests in the controller

```
def check_captcha
   return if verify_recaptcha
   self.resource = resource_class.new sign_in_params

   respond_with_navigational(resource) do
     flash.discard(:recaptcha_error)
     render :new
   end
end
```

The success flow the spec is successfully covering (because recaptcha is skipped on test
env).
But the alternative flow I couldn't test

I'm using this mock to change the value of `verify_recaptcha` to false:

`allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(false)`

But the `respond_with_navigational` doesn't work because the error object on the user model isn't populated.

How can I solve this?
I'm using simplecov and it alerts me to this alternate flow that wasn't covered by any tests

Comment: Have you enabled recaptcha in the test environment? https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#testing